# ComboBox remove blue underline

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have language `ComboBox` which works perfect, but after clicking to change the language then this weird blue underline appears. I'm not quite sure where this comes from

[image: Language ComboBox with a selected item that is underlined.]

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SupportedLanguages, Mode=OneTime}"
                Name="LanguageComboBox"
                Padding="2"
                BorderThickness="0"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguageName}" 
                Background="Transparent"
                UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="model:CountryFlagDto">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=LangKey, Converter={StaticResource CountryIdToFlagImageSourceConverter}}"
                            Width="23" Height="34"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Image size also matching with Width="23" Height="34" ? it looks like a focusing color.

Comment: @Expressingx Are you using a third-party library like MahApps.Metro or MaterialDesign?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can it be, that somewhere you have an implicit style for `ComboBox`? Try also to set explicitly `ComboBox.IsEditable = "False"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MaterialDesign in XAML, then this is caused by the text field decoration that is applied to the selected item. You can disable it by setting the `DecorationVisibility` attached property of the `TextFieldAssist` helper class to `Hidden` (or `Collapsed`).

```
<ComboBox materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden" ...>
```